# How can I gray out a menu item in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm building a program in PyQt where a user can choose from a set of selectable menu items. However, I want the user to only be able to click on things when certain conditions have been met. What I would like to know is, is it possible to gray out or completely disable an item in the menu area?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible to do something like this.

use `setDisabled` to do this.
 Here is an example of this working. 
 The parameter is a boolean, and setting it to True will make your object grey out.

```
self.FooBarMenuItem.setDisabled(True)
```

[image]

---

to turn it off, simply set the parameter's value to False

```
self.FooBarMenuItem.setDisabled(False)
```

[image]

---

You can also make items completely disappear by using the setVisible function

```
self.FooBarMenuItem.setVisible(False)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You just have to disable your item.

example:

```
button = QPushButton("EXPLODE EVERYTHING")

if presidentOfUsa:
    button.setDisable(False)
else:
    button.setDisable(True)
```